# Compose Navigation screen blinks when navigate to another screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, navigation-compose

When i am trying to navigate to another screen by .clickable on modifier i got this. Never faced such problem earlier. This is how i navigate and what i see on screen.

What i show if response from network is successful. onCategorySelectedListener is attached to CategoryGrid as shown below.

```
SuccessfulScreen(
            modifier = modifier,
            onCategorySelectedListener = {
                if (navController.currentDestination?.route != "${Destinations.SelectedCategoryScreen.route}/$it")
                    navController.navigate(
                        route = "${Destinations.SelectedCategoryScreen.route}/$it"
                    )
            },
            categories = state.categories
        )
```

```
CategoriesGrid(
            modifier = modifier.fadingEdge(topFade),
            categories = categories,
            onCategorySelectedListener = onCategorySelectedListener,
        )
```

Screen record: [What i see on screen](https://imgpile.com/i/D51u0R)

I am using androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.2

Comment: Issue doesn't seem to be related with navigation. It looks like there is unhandled state updation occuring on start of screen!

Comment: @Megh i now checked and actually composed function in NavGraph recomposed 3 times before i go to screen i need to go. So it's also ViewModel being recreated and previous screen being recomposed couple of times too. And I honestly don't know where to look at now.

P.S. I checked state when it recomposes and the thing is that it becomes new like if ViewModel just being created and then it fills up with info and recomposes. So I think that one of probable solutions may be to create dagger subcomponent not in composable functions but earlier. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured everything out. The thing was that I created ViewModel with Dagger similar to how I did it with Views. So I simply write some ViewModelFactory with map in it and so on but it didn't work so ViewModel was always being recreated and due to that fact new state was emitted and recomposition triggered. I searched in internet and found [this](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-and-jetpack-compose-integration-8a8d424ffdb4) nice solution and after a couple of changes that I needed for myself it now works perfectly. I still create ViewModel inside composable {} in my NavHost but now it is not recreated every time but created only once and then just reused by Dagger.

Comment: Maybe you can share viewmodel code and navigation component so that community members can help you optimise the code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I got the same issue having a "scaffold-per-screen" architecture. What helped, to my surprise, was lowering `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` version to 2.4.0-alpha04.